# Looping dynamic data in JavaScript append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add dynamic fields in my view with jQuery and it's working, **the issue that i have is to load my dynamic data** in appended part by jQuery.

**Here is my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var loopsData = [
      @foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
        value: '{{ $attribute->id }}',
        text: '{{ $attribute->title }}'
      }
      @unless($loop - > last),
      @endunless
      @endforeach
    ];

    console.log(loopsData);

    var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
    var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"col-md-12 mt-20\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
    var fName = $("<label for=\"title\">Title</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title[]\" class=\"form-control\" />");
    var fType = $("<label for=\"attribute_id\">Parent</label><select name=\"attribute_id\" id=\"attribute_id\" class=\"form-control\"><option value=\"\">Select</option><option value=" + loopsData['value'] + ">" + loopsData['text'] + "</option></select>");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\" value=\"-\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(fName);
    fieldWrapper.append(fType);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buildyourform">
  <div class="col-md-12 mt-20">
    Title
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 mt-20">
    Parent
    <select name="attribute_id" id="attribute_id" class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
      <option value="{{$attribute->id}}">{{$attribute->title}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- buttons -->
<input type="button" value="Add a field" class="add" id="add" />
<!-- buttons -->
```

## Issue

1. When I use `console.log(loopsData);` it returns my data correctly.
2. But in my form is says `undefined`

I think I need to use `$each` in this part:

```
<option value="+loopsData['value']+">"+loopsData['text']+"</option>
```

but when I used that i gets me syntax error.

## Help wanted

**I need your help to loop my code without getting syntax error?**

thanks.

Comment: You are not showing the full picture here. What is this @-notation, some templating? Like foreach, unless... Is this PHP/Laravel?

Comment: yes is laravel as my issue was about js i skip that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SOLVED

here is how i solved my problem thanks to those who vote-down without even trying to help!

First i added this code tho my script:

```
var loopsData = [
    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        { value: '{{ $attribute->id }}', text: '{{ $attribute->title }}' }
        @unless ($loop->last)
            ,
        @endunless
    @endforeach
];

var helpers = '';
$.each(loopsData, function(key, value) {
  helpers += '<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.text+'</option>';
});
```

And then I changed my append part to use `helpers` var instead of option html code.

```
<select name=\"attribute_id[]\" id=\"attribute_id\" class=\"form-control\"><option value=\"\">Select</option>"+helpers+"</select>
```

Here is full code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {

//my data from controller
            var loopsData = [
                @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                    { value: '{{ $attribute->id }}', text: '{{ $attribute->title }}' }
                    @unless ($loop->last)
                        ,
                    @endunless
                @endforeach
            ];
    //looping my data in jQuery and return result as option html
            var helpers = '';
            $.each(loopsData, function(key, value) {
              helpers += '<option value="'+value.value+'">'+value.text+'</option>';
// += will add new option to my select box for each one of my loop data
            });

//add it to my code
            var lastField = $("#buildyourform div:last");
            var intId = (lastField && lastField.length && lastField.data("idx") + 1) || 1;
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"col-md-4 mt-20\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
            fieldWrapper.data("idx", intId);
            var fName = $("<label for=\"title\">Title</label><input type=\"text\" name=\"title[]\" class=\"form-control\" />");
            var fType = $("<label for=\"attribute_id\">Parent</label><select name=\"attribute_id[]\" id=\"attribute_id\" class=\"form-control\"><option value=\"\">Select</option>"+helpers+"</select>");
            var removeButton = $("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus\"></i></button>");
            removeButton.click(function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
            fieldWrapper.append(fName);
            fieldWrapper.append(fType);
            fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
            $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);
        });
    });
```

Hope it helps someone else.